# ES6 Symbol properties not detected by Visual Studio Code Intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I have the following two objects in Visual Studio Code, each with one public and one private (via symbol) method:

```js
const symKey = Symbol();


/** @namespace */
var objLiteral = {
    literalPublicFn1() {},

    /**
     * You found the secret fn!
     */
    [symKey]() {},
};


/** @namespace */
var objAssigned = {};

/** @memberof objAssigned */
objAssigned.laterPublicFn1 = function() {};

/** 
 * You found the secret fn!
 * @memberof objAssigned 
 * */
objAssigned[symKey] = function () {}
```

For both objects, the public methods are autocompleted accurately. However, when I try to access their private methods, autocompletion only works for the object literal:

[image]

Whereas for the later-assigned object, no autocompletion appears whatsoever.

Any solutions to this, or is this just a limitation of VSC's intellisense?

Comment: I'd recommend not to call symbol-keyed properties "private" or even "secret". Better go with "clash-free".

Comment: I know, but I’d best most people that use them as properties do so in place of more robust privacy mechanisms. It’s about intent and preventing accidents, not security. Which is also why a still very common naming convention for what we otherwise call methods-I-can-use-but-you-should-not is to just begin their names with an `_`